# There is a way to receive RTSP stream (RTSP Client) and get access to the input raw buffer?

Tags: android, rtsp, rtsp-client

I'm trying to receive RTSP stream (playback) to android device and get access to video/audio tracks byte buffer pre/post decode.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Where there is a will there is a way.... so_rcvall...

Answer (score 1):

RTSP is not exactly handling the streams of data itself. It is more like controlling things for the protocols that actually handle data, like RTP/RTCP for example. RTSP acts for, say exchange SDP informations, start/stop playing, fast forward etc...

So if you want to access the raw content data, you should try to get deeper into those "content" layers.

If you try to use some library to fetch RTSP data, they probably rely on low level native (NDK) implementations or libs, and the transport data is most probably compressed or encrypted.
Which makes it very unlikely to get the content data easily, or should I say possible.

You still have the possibility to implement your own RTSP client (not too difficult, you need to implement the basics of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7826), then handle the management of the data to some other libs whom you get source code, such as FFMPEG, and dive into the source, write the necessary (native) code to hook and get the data, recompile and add to your project.
Far less easy.